# How can I use the GetDefaultAudioEndpoint() of IMMDeviceEnumerator interface in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Please see this post:
[DSPack - How to get the default device for sound output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152259/dspack-how-to-get-the-default-device-for-sound-output)

which I had also posted here: http://www.progdigy.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4993

As per this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/108fc80c-5d09-4c09-a806-58339dfb7197/

it is possible to get it using GetDefaultAudioEndpoint() method of IMMDeviceEnumerator interface.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Will it work on both Windows 7 and Windows XP?

NOTE: I am interested in Delphi code to get the default device using the above functions please.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it work on both Windows 7 and Windows XP?

No, as the minimum supported client for [IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is Windows Vista.